# python accessing elements in a dictionary inside dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, riot-games-api

I get a response from riot's server:

```
def main():
    api = RiotAPI('dec34559a91-ad8b-4fd2-b49a-bae3b4524522b8a')
    summoner_name = str(input("Please enter the summoner ID\n"))
    if summoner_name == "":
        summoner_name = "zLKida"
    r = api.get_summoner_by_name(summoner_name)
    print(r)
```

which prints out something like this:

```
{'zlkidda': {'profileIconId': 539, 'id': 27003987, 'summonerLevel': 30, 'name': 'zLKidda', 'revisionDate': 1444958792000}}
```

I have no idea how I can access the data inside the dictionary. 
Note that it is returned as a dict not a string or anything else.

I have tried:

```
print(r['zlkidda'].['profileIconId'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the dot:

```
print(r['zlkidda']['profileIconId'])
```

or for your code specifically, reusing teh `summoner_name` variable:

```
print(r[summoner_name]['profileIconId'])
```

You are using [*subscriptions*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#subscriptions) here; the `[...]` selects one element from the container.

`.` notation on the other hand, is used for [*attribute referencing*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#attribute-references), use that for things like `dict` methods:

```
print(list(r['zlkidda'].keys()))
```

Comment: `print(r[summoner_name]['profileIconId'])` provides the error: KeyError: 'zLKidda'

Comment: @LukeGoddard: Note the uppercase `LK` but the returned dictionary uses all lowercase. Either enter an all-lowercase name, or use `summoner_name.lower()` when subscribing `r`.

Comment: Omg you're a genius thanks i dont think i would have noticed that